# ChartJS Radar Chart Skip label Ticks

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have created a Radar chart with 360 labels; for each degree one. But I don't want to show them all on the scale. How can skip ticks?

I would like to skip some labels on the x-axis because there are too many points. I have tried all the following settings. Can any body please help me?

I have tried to make the labels empty in the array, but then the tooltip those not work

I tried both make the font-size smaller as well as skipping ticks:

```
{
  type: 'radar',
  pointDot: false,
  scaleOverride: true,
  scaleSteps: 4,
  scaleStepWidth: 5,
  scaleStartValue: 0,
  data: {
    labels: [],
    datasets: []
  },
  options: {
    elements: {
      line: {
        tension:0,
        borderWidth:3
      }
    },
    scales: {
      ticks: {
        max: 100,
        fontSize: 6,
        autoSkip: true,
        stepSize:50
      },
      gridLines: {
        display: false
      },
      pointLabels: {
        fontSize: 6
      }
    },
    legend: {
      display: false,
      labels: {
        fontSize: 6
      }
    },
    labels: {
      fontSize: 6
    }
  },
  pointLabelFontSize: '6px'
}
```

I have ChartJS version 2.5.0

The result is as follows:
[Output of graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUQsc.jpg)

Comment: do you wanna hide all the labels?

Comment: Sorry for my late response. No; I would like skip for example each fourth label. Or only showing: ['0', '90','180','270', '359']